# updater-script—Universal Method of Mounting partitions

Tags: adb

I'm trying to create a universal updater-script but I'v run into a bit of a wall. I can't find any universal way to mount a given partition.

In order to mount something in the [edify scripting language](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/inside_packages) I need to provide
a `fs_type`, `partition_type`, `name`, `mount_point`. I expect `partition_type`, `name`, `mount_point` to be fairly universal, but `fs_type` could be all over the place.

My only idea is to try mounting in a bunch of different filesystems and checking after each attempt if it's mounted.

I will have **root** access to the device over `adb` beforehand. Is there a reasonable/programmatic way to do this with `adb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the recovery has `busybox` (e.g. TWRP for most if not all devices) you could simply call `run_program("/sbin/busybox", "mount", "/system");`. I wrote my own updater-script and this worked fairly well since the Android 5.x days.

Comment: I couldn't find this information anywhere else! Thanks a ton! I was aware that you could run programs from the updater script but didn't know exactly what busybox was for.